# Gson escaping double quotes in HashMap serialization even with disableHtmlEscaping

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I want to convert a `HashMap` to a JSON string with Gson where one of the map's values has double quotes. I do not want those double quotes to be escaped, but when converting to a JSON string with `disableHtmlEscaping` in my `GsonBuilder`, it still escapes the double quotes

I have a HashMap with the following String keys and String values

```
{
  "test1":"[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]"
}
```

When I try to serialize this map with gson after disabling HTML escaping with this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
return gson.toJson(map);
```

It returns the following string:

```
{"test1":"[{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}]"}
```

Also tried:

- manually escaping the strings before serializing
- setPrettyPrinting
- converting the map into a JsonTree and getting that as a String using getAsString and toString

None of those worked. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how I can convert that map to a string without escaping the double quotes?

I want the serialized map to look like

```
{"test1":"[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior and cannot be disabled. Apparently your value for the `test1` key is a string, so any `"` it contains must be escaped; otherwise they are misinterpreted as the end of the string.

For example let's look at your desired JSON output:

```json
{"test1":"[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]"}
```

This is not actually valid JSON. It starts with:

- object `{`

  - name `"test1"`
  - string value `"[{"`

And the remainder is invalid. You can see this in your local editor with JSON validation support (for example VS Code) or for example on https://jsonlint.com/.

I assume the problem here is the data you pass to `Gson.toJson`. You currently seem to pass `HashMap<String, String>` but probably actually want to pass `HashMap<String, List<...>>`. So something already converted the map value to String before you used Gson.
If you used `HashMap<String, List<...>>`, then you get the (probably desired) output:

```json
{"test1":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}
```

(note the missing `"` in front and behind the value)